# Problem with accessing webpages once hosted on server

Tags: html, reactjs, web-hosting

I have created a website using React.JS however I have now hosted the website ` but I am unable to access other pages except the homepage. I created the website using react components as illustrated below could this be the issue? For example, after I click the About webpage link it directs me to a 404 page not found. But in development , my navigation system is working perfectly?

```
const Services = () => {

  return (
    <Container className='services' id='services'>
      <div className='container-fluid' style={textStyle}>
        <p>Do you need a website for your business?</p>
        <p>Do you have an app idea?</p>
        <p>Do you need advice on how to improve your website or app?</p>
        <p>Contact us!</p>
      </div>

      <div className='container-fluid' id='workflow' style={workflowTextStyle}>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <i className='fas fa-comments fa-3x' />
            <p>Plan - Tell us what you need</p>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <i className='fas fa-pencil-alt fa-3x' />
            <p>Design - How do you want your website to look and function</p>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <i className='fas fa-code fa-3x' />
            <p>Development - Regular updates after developments</p>
          </Col>

          <Col>
            <i className='fas fa-check-circle fa-3x' />
            <p>Review - Customer Review Sessions throughout development</p>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Services;
```

Comment: Are you using webpack in development using [historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the React docs https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment on how to launch a deployment react server. Specifically, I suspect this is what you need:

If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a .htaccess file in the public folder that looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It will get copied to the build folder when you run npm run build.

Caveat from Quentin's comment: If you want to make your website more SEO indexable and Accessible, other solutions such as NextJS may be more appropriate for your project. https://nextjs.org/

Comment: That just duplicates the page on every URL, it's terrible for SEO and accessibility. Use something like next.js instead.

Comment: @Quentin That's a bit outside the scope of the question. A better solution, based on the code posted, would be to just use static html files.

Comment: Im using react.js which is a single page application , addtional html files isnt an option , i dont think?

Comment: @John the answer I posted should work for your application, but as Quentin pointed out, it's not great for SEO or accessibility. Because your component just seems to return a bunch of html, with no logic, I would question whether React is needed at all. Maybe it is in other components. Anyway, if you must use React, do what I posted and it will work, then look into other solutions (such as NextJS as Quentin suggested) for down the road.

Comment: yea , I was just learning react. its just a static website for myself . Thanks

Comment: I will add @Quentin's advice as a caveat to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on hosting matters but since I faced and solved this too, I'll answer to my abilities.

Building a react application generates a single index.html file. If you are serving via nginx, you can easily configure all the routes to be directed to that `index.html`. However, in a shared hosting environment (cpanel), when you upload your build, it uploads to one folder and only route to that folder directs to that `index.html` and writing any other route will direct you to another shared hosting directory hence you are facing the 404 issue. The solution is to change the `.htaccess` file accordingly.

Comment: That just duplicates the page on every URL, it's terrible for SEO and accessibility. Use something like next.js instead.

Comment: @Quentin so do you think using next.js within my navigation component should solve the problem?

Comment: @John — next.js is something used around the entire app, not inside a component